# Optimal way for storing compressed sets

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, set, compression

As title says, I am searching for the optimal way of storing sets in memory. I am only interested in sets of bytes (array of integers from `0` to `255` where order is not important). It is not required that encoding/decoding be fast. The only necessary thing is that sets should require as little memory as possible.

The first method I came up with is to allocate array of `256` bits (`32` bytes) for each set and the bit at position `n` tells if there is `n` in the set or not. The problem with this approach is because it requires the same amount of memory even if the set are mostly empty (has only few elements).

The second approach I tried is to store sets as regular arrays. So, if a set contains `n` elements, then it will require `n + 1` bytes to be stored. The first byte represents the number of elements and other bytes represents elements. But, as we know, order in sets are not important, so something strongly tells me that there must be  a way to impove this.

My third attempt is to enumerate all possible sets and the just store the index of set (integer representing its index in list of all possible sets of bytes). But, it turned out that it is absolutelly equivalent as the first approach. Basically, I will still need `32` bytes to store any set, so it is not very useful.

Fourth attempt I made is based on my second approach. I noticed that is the set contains `n` elements it will, of course, require `n + 1` bytes (if I use my second method). But, if, for example, element `k` appeared in set (actually in array, because in my second attempt I store sets as arrays), then it cannot appear again. Basically, if `k` appears again, then it must mean something different (maybe `k - 1`). So, I did some optimizations and I noticed that I can save some bytes if I differently encode each next element (for examle `[3, 3, 5, 7]` is interpreted as set of `3` elements whose elements are `{3, 4, 5}` (every next element is decreased by its index) and `[3, 3, 5, 6]` is interpreted as `{3, 4, 2}` (notice that `3` and `4` already exists, so `6` is decreased by `2` and it becomes `4`, but `4` exists and `3` exists, so it must be `2`)). But how can this approach can actually save bytes? I experimented and realized that I can order elements in the array to make it possible, for some cases, to avoid using high bit to encode element, so I saved `1` bit per element, which is about `n / 16` bytes saved (which is `n / 2 * 1 / 8`).

Fifth approach I made is similar to my second approach, but it differently interpret number fo elements. If number of elements are less than `128` then it normally read all the lements from the following array in the memory. But, if the number fo ellements is greater than `128` then it creates a full set and then just remove elements from the following array in memory. On average, is saves a lot of bytes, but it is still far away from optimal.

My last attempt (sixth attempt) is to enumerate just some sets (for example create a list of sets which will contain: full set, set with only even numbers, set with only odd numbers, set with elements less than 128, set with elements greater than 128, etc) and then to use elements from that list and basic set operations (union, intersection, etc) to reconstruct original set. It will require few bytes for each base set we use from the list and it will require a few bits for union or intersection operations, and of course one byte for length of our sequence. It very depends on number of elements in the base set list which should be hardcoded, but it seems hard to preoperly create and properly chose elements which are in that list. Anyway, something tells me that this is not very clever approach.

But hat is actually the most optimal way? Something tells me that my fourth attempt is not so bad, but can we do better? The sets I opereate with have random number of elements, so on average `128` elements per set, so I am looking for a way to allocate `128` bits (`16` bytes) per set. The best I did so far is using my fourth approach which is far away from my goal.

Just to mention again, speed is not important. Encoding/decoding may be extremelly slow, the only important thing is that sets require as little amount of memory as possible. When I said *"in memory"* I meant encoded in memory (compressed). Also, I am interested in as little bits as possible (not only bytes) because I want to store billions of sets compressed on my HDD, so it is important to calculate average amount of bits I need for each set so I know how many resources are available to what I want to achieve.

P.S. If you want some code (but I really don't see why would you) I can post here my solutions I made in C for all of these approaches. Anyway, I am not asking for code or technical details how to implement this in specific programming language, I am just asking for method/algorithm for compressing sets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of set sizes? You seem to feel that most sets are small; is that true, or are you just thinking that you should be able to do better with small sets even if they are rare?

Comment: Is there any sort of bias in the sets, i.e. are some values or combinations of values more likely to be present than others?

Comment: How are you figuring that "2^256 bits" is equivalent to 32 bytes? It's _much_ larger than that… same goes for "2^128 bits" later on.

Comment: @rici. Number of elements are randomly distributed. For each number `n` from `0 - 255` it is same probability that a set contains `n` elements. I don't think sets with *"fewer elements"* should necessary require fewer amount of memory. But, on average, it should be possible not to use `32` bits for every single set.

Comment: @m69. Unfortunatelly not. Elements and number of elements are randomly distributed.

Comment: Actually, if it is really true that set populations are evenly distributed, then compression is possible. But I suspect that wasn't what you meant. Is the (single) set containing all elements as frequent as all sets of 128 elements together (of which there are more than subatomc particles in the universe)? Or is it as likely as any other set?

Comment: You could try and see if using 32 extra bits (4 bytes) to specify which consecutive sets of 8 bits in the ordered set have nonzero entries (and are thus stored), reduces the average size of the stored set. In the worst case, it increases the size by 12.5%. Anyway, a billion (1,000,000,000) uncompressed sets take 32 gigabytes, which is not *that* much. When you do have the data for the first billion (or, say, 2³⁰) sets, it is much easier to compare compression schemes to find a suitable one; why try to find one beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method (and the third method, which is equivalent) is already optimal. It cannot be improved.

There are 2<sup>256</sup> possible sets of numbers you're working with. By the pigeonhole principle, you need 2<sup>256</sup> numbers to identify them all, and you'll need 256 bits to represent those numbers. Any method of identifying the sets which used fewer than 256 bits would leave at least one pair (and probably many pairs) of sets sharing the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^256 possible sets of bytes.

If all sets are equally likely, then the best you can do is to use a constant 256 bits (32 bytes) to indicate which of the 2^256 possibilities you have.

You seem not to like this idea, because you think that sets with only a few elements should take fewer bits.  But if they are no more likely to occur than any other sets, then that would not be optimal.

If sets with fewer elements *are* more likely, then using a constant 32-bytes is *not* optimal, but the optimal encoding depends on the precise probability distribution of possible sets, which you haven't given.  The relevant concept from information theory is "entropy": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Succinctly,  in an optimal encoding, the average number of bits required will be the **Sum_of_all Pᵢ * -log₂(Pᵢ)** over all 2^256 possible sets, where each **Pᵢ** is the probability of having to encode a particular set (all the Pᵢ must sum to 1)

If the number of elements is the *only* thing that you think should affect the size of the encoding, then you can't go too far wrong with something like this:

1) Use 1 byte to write out the number of elements in the set.  There are 257 possible set sizes, but you can use 0 for both 0 and 256 elements.

2) Write out the index of the set in an enumeration of all sets with that length.  (If you wrote a 0 then you need 1 bit to indicate the empty or full set).  If the set is known to have N elements, then the number of bits required for this number will be **log₂(256!/(N!*(256-N)!)**

Comment: But there are more than 2^248 sets with lengths 110 ~ 146, so combined with the length you'd need more than 256 bits for these sets.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  You can only have a 256 bit maximum if the encodings for all sets are the same length.  If you make some shorter, then you have to make others longer.